# STL generation for Ball-in-a-maze puzzle

Tags: graphics, regions, opencascade, stl-format

As a minimal example, consider:

```
annuli = {Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.8`, 1}, {1.3681023133518435`, 
    6.255024218935966`}], 
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {1.8`, 2}, {2.9394676092071563`, 
    8.524521215589012`}], 
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {2.8`, 3}, {5.390068220020829`, 
    11.207832393335261`}], 
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {3.8`, 4}, {1.847790960182163`, 
    7.781910416962884`}], 
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {4.8`, 5}, {5.369176063296676`, 
    11.373108690157169`}]}

regU = RegionUnion@(RegionProduct[annuli[[#]] , 
      Line[{{0}, {0.8}}]] & /@ Range[Length@annuli])

Region[RegionUnion[
  regU
  , Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0, -0.75}}, 5.8]
  , Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.75}, {0, 0, -1.5}}, 6.0]
  ]
 , Boxed -> True
 , BoxRatios -> Automatic
 , Axes -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}, {-2, 2}}
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 ]
```

[image]

Using `Show`, a better rendering is generated for annuli on top.

```
Show[Region /@ (RegionProduct[annuli[[#]] , Line[{{0}, {0.8}}]] & /@ 
    Range[Length@annuli])]
```

[image]

**Question:** I want to generate a STL file from this. How can I improve the resolution of the structure shown in the first graphic?

Any suggestions, tips, improvements will be gratefully received.

Comment: Removing ```PlotRange``` seems to do it.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that I struggle with when using Region stuff. Once little details start getting added in, it's hard to maintain a decent resolution. You asked how to improve resolution, but you say you want to generate an STL, and so maybe a little thinking outside the box is warranted. If you have tools to process the STL after generating with Mathematica, then (1) export STL for each component of the thing and use some other tool to recombine them...

Comment: (2) use the CSGRegion functions (but unfortunately it looks like they don't handle the Product that you use to create the extruded annuli)...

Comment: (3) try to draw it with Graphics primitives, and use DiscretizeGraphics

Comment: (4) since this can be created with simple objects (cylinders and wedges), do this entirely outside of Mathematica (e.g. this would be fairly easy in OpenSCAD).

Comment: (5) RegionPlot3D will take a PlotPoints option, and sometimes this can sufficiently improve the resolution, but in my experience the cost is long wait times.

Comment: @lericr, why would you use an external CAD system when Mathematica ships with it's own?

Comment: @user21 I guess I don't know what CAD system you're referring to. All I can say is that the functions that seem most amenable to generating printable object, i.e. the Region* functions, just don't perform well compared to other programs that are special-built for that purpose. The new CSGRegion* functions are much better.

Comment: @user21 Just saw your answer with a link to OpenCascadeLink. I wasn't aware of this. Where have you been for the last 10 years as I desperately looked for a Mathematica-only solution for my printing projects?

Comment: @user21 side question: how do people find these packages?

Comment: @user21 sorry for highjacking this, but OMG, this looks incredible!

Comment: @lericr, glad you like it. Note, that OpenCascadeLink is on [github](https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink) and is waiting for your contributions ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html), which comes with Mathematica, will give you excellent results. We start by loading the package and writing a little helper function to convert the annuli to polygons in 3D space which we then rotate in 3D.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
f[\[Theta]_, r_] := Sequence[r*Cos[\[Theta]], r*Sin[\[Theta]]]
makePoly[\[Theta]_, {rin_, rout_}, {h1_, h2_}] := 
 Polygon[{{f[\[Theta], rin], h1}, {f[\[Theta], rout], 
    h1}, {f[\[Theta], rout], h2}, {f[\[Theta], rin], h2}}]
```

Create the polygon and visualize:

```
poly = makePoly @@@ 
   Transpose[{annuli[[All, 3, 1]], annuli[[All, 2]], 
     ConstantArray[{0, 0.8}, Length[annuli]]}];

Graphics3D[poly]
```

Convert the polygon to OpenCascade shapes and rotate them by the given amount:

```
shapes = OpenCascadeShape /@ poly;
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
sweeps = 
  MapThread[
   OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[#1, axis, #2] &, {shapes, 
    Subtract @@@ annuli[[All, 3]][[All, {2, 1}]]}];
```

Create the two cylinders and make a union of all of it:

```
cyls = OpenCascadeShape /@ {Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0, -0.75}}, 
     5.8], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.75}, {0, 0, -1.5}}, 6.0]};
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{cyls, sweeps}]];
```

If you want to inspect before exporting use a wireframe:

```
OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union][
 "Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[Orange]]]
```

[image]

Ah, yes, and export:

```
OpenCascadeShapeExport["~/test.stl", union]
```

Have a look at the aforementioned tutorial and also this [Helical Bevelgear](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/HelicalBevelGear.html) example to get an idea of the scope of OpenCascadeLink.

Answer (score 7):

You could convert it to BoundaryMeshRegion and do operations:

```
regU = (RegionProduct[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@annuli[[#]], 
      Line[{{0}, {0.8}}]] & /@ Range[Length@annuli]);

cylinder = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ {Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0.2}, {0, 
       0, -0.75}}, 5.8], 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.75}, {0, 0, -1.5}}, 6.0]};

RegionUnion[Flatten[{cylinder, regUU}]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Although `CSGRegion` is hard to export to `stl` upto the 13.0.1 version.

```
annuliCylinder[{x_, y_}, {r1_, r2_}, {θ1_, θ2_}, {h1_, 
   h2_}] := 
 CSGRegion[
  "Difference", {CSGRegion[
    "Difference", {Cylinder[{{x, y, h1}, {x, y, h2}}, r2], 
     Cylinder[{{x, y, h1}, {x, y, h2}}, r1]}], 
   Parallelepiped[{x, y, 
     h1}, {{r2*Cos[θ1], r2*Sin[θ1], 
      h1}, {r2*Cos[θ2], r2*Sin[θ2], h1}, {x, y, 2 h2}}]}]
data = Append[#, {0, 1}] & /@ 
   List @@@ {Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.8`, 1}, {1.3681023133518435`, 
       6.255024218935966`}], 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {1.8`, 2}, {2.9394676092071563`, 
       8.524521215589012`}], 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {2.8`, 3}, {5.390068220020829`, 
       11.207832393335261`}], 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {3.8`, 4}, {1.847790960182163`, 
       7.781910416962884`}], 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {4.8`, 5}, {5.369176063296676`, 
       11.373108690157169`}]};
CSGRegion["Union", {annuliCylinder @@@ data, 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0, -0.75}}, 5.8], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.75}, {0, 0, -1.5}}, 6.0]} // Flatten, 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]